# how to restrict access to certain pages on my website

Tags: php

my website is http://setch.me

I have a page that I use to add new entries to the artists table, how do I set a simple `username/password` to this page with normal php(no framework)?

I've looked it up and I found similar questions but none of them is using php only

Comment: you can try basic HTTP Header Authentication for simple username/password authentication. See here at http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply you just need to create a form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user"/>
<input type="password" name="pass"/>
</form>
```

And submit data and compare it with your private username and password 
example

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
// Here you put you own login data you can use mysql to get it
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";
$username_post = htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]);
$password_post = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"]);
if(($username_post == $username) && ($password_post == $password)) {
session_start();
$_SESSION["admin"] = $username;
}
}
?>
```

and put this code in page that you want to add new entries

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION["admin"])) {die();}
?>
```

Comment: it's working, thank you!, just to add for whoever comes later, in the form you also need a submit input with name="submit"

Comment: Yes you need it

Answer (score 0):

[Php-login](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal) comes with three versions. The first one (One-file version) maybe is what you are looking for.